# SwiftUI Tap Gesture trigger order is not always the same in case it's applied to a NavigationView and its subview - a Circle view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I'm an iOS beginner.

I'm facing an issue with the trigger order of Tap Gesture which is applied to NavigationView and its subview - a Circle view.

When I tap on the Circle view, I expect that the system always prioritizes the Tap Gesture action of the Circle view over the Tap Gesture action of the NavigationView, BUT the result is not always like that.

Specifically, sometimes the system gives:

```
    
    Navigation tapped
    Circle tapped
```

sometimes the system gives

```
    
    Circle tapped
    Navigation tapped
```

You can watch this issue on **[Youtube](https://youtu.be/mLgKPj7G7UY)**.

The code is as below or on **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/projectxmaker/a05e38ea37367a3458b29955886807fd)**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
//                Button {
//                    print("Circle tapped")
//                } label: {
//                    Circle()
//                        .fill(.red)
//                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
//                }
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Circle tapped")
                    }
            }
        }
//        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({ _ in
//            print("Navigation tapped")
//        }))
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Navigation tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried (as commented code) but failed:

- use simulatneousGesture modifier.
- [UPDATED Nov 3, 2022] use Button w/ label as a Circle.

Is there any way to make the system always prioritize the Tap Gesture of the Circle over the Tap Gesture of the Navigation View?

Thanks for your reading and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you create a button and have the label of that button as circle? On a side note if you are starting a new project use `NavigationStack` or `NavigationSplitView` if possible.

Comment: @user1046037 thanks for your help. I tried your solution but it doesn't work unfortunately :( . I recorded a video of this try, you can find it on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/mLgKPj7G7UY). Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Just curious, may be you could explain what you are trying to achieve and why the order matters?

Comment: @user1046037 ah, the code I showed here is just a simple version of the issue. In fact, the issue is about the long press gesture which is applied to the Circles and the NavigationView contains those Circles. When the users do a long press on a Circle, a Dialog containing actions for that Circle will be shown. When the users do a long press on other positions on the screen that is not about a Circle, a deletion option will be positioned at the top left of every Circle. Therefore, the long press gesture on Circle must be prioritized over the long press gesture on the NavigationView.

Comment: Keep it simple, just use a `.contextMenu`, refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contextmenu(menuitems:)

Comment: @user1046037 thank you very much, I haven't known about contextMenu before. I applied it and it works very well. Just one more question, originally, I'd allow the users to do the long press on a Circle to show a Dialog after 1 second, if the users keep pressing the Circle in next 2 seconds, a deletion option will appear at the top left of every Circle, this scenario is similar to the way we do the long press on any app icon on iOS screen. After implementing the menu content on the Circle, the long press gesture of NavigationView doesn't affect the Circle anymore. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Use tap gesture (or button) and context menu, we can't control seconds with contextMenu or tap gesture / button. Also always keep in mind about the XY problem, asking the question effectively would result in better answers. Refer https://xyproblem.info

Comment: It is important to understand the design guidelines, I am not sure if yours is a standard app or a drawing app. If it is a standard app and you are new to the platform stick with the basics. IMHO it would be best if you spent more time learning SwiftUI before building apps.

Comment: @user1046037 I got it. Currently, I use context menu on Circle, long press gesture on empty space to trigger the action that shows all deletion options on all Circles, tap gesture on Circle and empty space to hide all deletion options.

Comment: @user1046037 I've read XY problem and realized that I should describe the issue fully next time to get better answers. I'm truly sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @user1046037 I will take the time to read the design guidelines and learn SwiftUI. Thank you very much for giving me your wonderful advice.

Comment: Good luck, the time you invest now in learning will help you in the long run, Apple has really nice videos start with https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10119. Good luck!